# Can a radio button in a form be used to select another radio button in the same form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a HTML form that has 2 groups of radio buttons. I need the first group to also change the selection on the second group, i.e.

Group 1 has options A & B, Group 2 has options C & D;
when I select A, I need the form to also select C; when I select B, I need the form to also select D.
I need A & C selected by default when the page loads.
A & C will always be paired; B & D will always be paired.

I know this sounds impractical, but the reason is that this form is sending its responses to another provider's form where I can't edit the fields. They have effectively got a duplicate question in their form (same question just slightly different wording), and I don't want my users to have to answer the same question twice, so I would hope to hide the buttons for C & D from view.

The "name" on the each group is different, and the "value" & "id" for each radio button is unique.

Can this be done? JQuery & JS solutions are welcome.

```
<label for="buyer-select">
    <div class="user-select-label">Buyer</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="answers[1234][answers]" id="buyer-select" class="buyer-select" value="buyer" checked>

<label for="agent-select">
    <div class="user-select-label">Agent</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="answers[1234][answers]" id="agent-select" class="agent-select" value="broker">
            
<label class="label-text" for="buyer">Buyer</label>
<input type="radio" name="agent" id="buyer" value="false">

<label class="label-text" for="agent">Agent</label>
<input type="radio" name="agent" id="agent" value="true">
```

Comment: Yes, this can be done. What problem are you having implementing it?

Comment: If you're hiding the second set of radio buttons, why don't you just replace them with a hidden input? Then just set the value of the hidden input to the corresponding radio button value.

Comment: Also provide some code you have tried till now or needed to produce the problem

Comment: I've updated my question to include some code. I'm ok with HTML & CSS, but JS and Jquery are new to me so I'm a bit lost.

@Barmar - the radio button values don't match between the 2 groups so I can't reuse the value in a hidden field.

Comment: You need to post the JS code that tries to solve the problem, not just the HTML.

Comment: I mean you use the value that the second radio button would have, not the value of the first radio button.

Comment: @Barmar - that's where I need the help. I don't know what JS to use. I'm a novice at this and hoping that someone here knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the `checked` property of the corresponding button.

```js
document.getElementById("buyer").checked = true;
document.getElementById("buyer-select").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("buyer").checked = true;
});

document.getElementById("agent-select").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("agent").checked = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="buyer-select">
    <div class="user-select-label">Buyer</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="answers[1234][answers]" id="buyer-select" class="buyer-select" value="buyer" checked>

<label for="agent-select">
    <div class="user-select-label">Agent</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="answers[1234][answers]" id="agent-select" class="agent-select" value="broker">

<br>

<label class="label-text" for="buyer">Buyer</label>
<input type="radio" name="agent" id="buyer" value="false">

<label class="label-text" for="agent">Agent</label>
<input type="radio" name="agent" id="agent" value="true">
```

You can also replace the second set of radio buttons with a single hidden input. Put the values that would have been sent by the radio button into the value of the hidden input.

```js
document.getElementById("buyer-select").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("buyer-agent").value = "false";
});

document.getElementById("agent-select").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("buyer-agent").value = "true";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="buyer-select">
    <div class="user-select-label">Buyer</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="answers[1234][answers]" id="buyer-select" class="buyer-select" value="buyer" checked>

<label for="agent-select">
    <div class="user-select-label">Agent</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="answers[1234][answers]" id="agent-select" class="agent-select" value="broker">

<input type="hidden" name="agent" id="buyer-agent" value="false">
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need - thanks! I just have one issue: when the page loads, the "checked" state is enabled for the first "Buyer" option, but nothing is selected for the second one. It requires the user to click the first "Buyer" option. I need both "Buyer" options to be set by default, and then changeable if "agent" is clicked.

Comment: Just set its `.checked` property in JavaScript, the same way it's done in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted:

[image]

If yes, try this code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name="pet"]').change(function() {
    var $radiobutton = $("input[value='"+$(this).val()+"']");
    $radiobutton.prop("checked", true);
    });
    $('input[type=radio][name="pet2"]').change(function() {
    var $radiobutton = $("input[value='"+$(this).val()+"']");
    $radiobutton.prop("checked", true);
    });
  }, false);
</script>
</head>

<h2>Select a Pet</h2>
<div>
  <input name="pet" type="radio" value="dog" /><span>Dog</span>
  <input name="pet" type="radio" value="cat" /><span>Cat</span>
  <input name="pet" type="radio" value="fish" /><span>Fish</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input name="pet2" type="radio" value="dog" /><span>Dog</span>
  <input name="pet2" type="radio" value="cat" /><span>Cat</span>
  <input name="pet2" type="radio" value="fish" /><span>Fish</span>
</div>
```

Comment: A stack snippet would be better than an image.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua but that solution depends on the values of the first set and second set being the same - mine don't match up.